# Carriage return being added to Azure CLI -o tsv output - 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url

Tags: bash, azure-cli

On a particular machine I experience that a CR (0x0D) is added to `-o tsv` single value output

```
az resource delete --ids $(az sf cluster show --cluster-name my-cluster --query id -o tsv) --verbose
```

which results in an error:

```
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../resourcegroups/.../providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/my-cluster%0D?api-version=2020-03-01
#->>>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

see also https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15745

Answer (score 3):

Following the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13573#issuecomment-888791313) in @kaiWalters [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66527152/30225)  I checked which version of `az` I was running under `wsl` and found it was later, but from the `windows` installation

```
$ which az
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/CLI2/wbin/az
```

Installing a specific version for `debian`/`ubuntu` in `wsl` [from Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt#option-1-install-with-one-command)

```
$ curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
.
.
.
$ which az
/usr/bin/az
```

you can now see the difference with the Linux version

```
$ storageId=$(/usr/bin/az storage account show --name "$storageAccountName" -o tsv --query id)
$ echo $storageId | wc -c
135
```

and using the `windows` version

```
$ storageId=$(az storage account show --name "$storageAccountName" -o tsv --query id)
$ echo $storageId | wc -c
136
```

Moral of the story? *use the `Linux` version under `WSL` to make `-o tsv` not append the carriage return!*

Answer (score 1):

As I was absolutely sure that this had been working before on another machine I was checking `az --version`.

Upgrading from outdated Azure CLI `2.9.1` to `2.20.0` resolved the issue.

It seems to be related to `CRLF` / `LF` handling in `WSL` - [see here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13573#issuecomment-650686531).